# Serilog clear providers from nuget package

Tags: c#, serilog

this is my question :

I'm working creating a library to allow team to implements Opentelemtry exporter to the logs, in this particular case Using Serilog provider :

I want to override if exist any serilog configuration in the application and use the configuration that we are going to provide with the nuget package :

Insise the nuget package i thinking to use (just and example , i know i need to add the exporter , etc...):

Receiving the builder or the service in my method and do this  :

```
var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.Console()
    .WriteTo.File("", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
    .CreateLogger();
builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
builder.Logging.AddSerilog(logger);
```

This configuration happens before or after the configuration added directly on the api ?

Comment: I am having really hard time trying to figure out what you are trying to ask.  Sorry